# How to make subdomains for cities on laravel (almost succeeded)?

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-routing

My question of the day)
I have already implemented subdomains for cities on Laravel, but I ran into a problem!
I apologize for my english)))

**I want to:**

```
NewYork was without a subdomain website.ru
California with a subdomain California.website.ru
Texas with a subdomain Texas.website.ru
NewYork == null
```

**I did this:**
*Database*

```
alias      | name
-------------------------
null       | NewYork
california | California
texas      | Texas
```

*Route*

```
Route::group([
     'domain' => '{city_alias}.website.ru',
     'namespace' => 'Available',
 ], function (){
     Route::get('/', 'IndexController@index')->name('index');
 });
```

Links in blade

```
route('category.one', [$city_one->alias, $category_one->alias])
```

Controller

```
class IndexController extends Controller 
{
    public function index($city_alias)
    {
        $city_one = City::cityAlias($city_alias)->first();
        return view('........');
    }
}
```

The problem is with the city of NewYork!
How can I make NewYork without a subdomain?? + less when to write.

**I found a function here, maybe it's the case?**
Illuminate\Routing\Route.php

```
    /**
     * Get or set the domain for the route.
     *
     * @param  string|null  $domain
     * @return $this|string|null
     */
    public function domain($domain = null)
    {
        if (is_null($domain)) {
            return $this->getDomain();
        }

        $parsed = RouteUri::parse($domain);

        $this->action['domain'] = $parsed->uri;

        $this->bindingFields = array_merge(
            $this->bindingFields, $parsed->bindingFields
        );

        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: it doesn't work)

Comment: Which answer did you try?

Comment: app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php   
```
public function boot()
{
    \Route::pattern('domain', '[a-z0-9.\-]+'); 
    parent::boot();
}
```                  and MiddleWare

Comment: Who of the answers in the linked question used that?

Answer (score 1):

You can make the parameter optional and set a default value:

```
Route::group([
     'domain' => '{city_alias?}.website.ru',
     'namespace' => 'Available',
 ], function (){
     Route::get('/', 'IndexController@index')->name('index');
 });
```

```
class IndexController extends Controller 
{
    public function index($city_alias = 'NewYork')
    {
        $city_one = City::cityAlias($city_alias)->first();
        return view('........');
    }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately I tried it this way
404

Comment: $city_alias = null    (Database NewYork)

Comment: And? Do you get a 404 or what happens?

Comment: i'm getting a 404 error

Comment: Ah, thanks. It was worth a try.

Comment: as soon as I do: ({city_alias?}) all subdomains do not work. And before that, it only didn't work website.ru, which gave a 404 error

Comment: Thank you for this, I think it needs to be caught somewhere

Comment: As kapil-garg explains in the post I linked under your question, the problem is the dot. I personally don't like their solution and would go with j-davises